# Docker Jenkins Container crashes with SEVERE jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed ConfigurationAsCode.init

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-plugins, devops

Using docker jenkins lts image to run the jenkins service, it was working fine on spin up, the container apparently was stopped, after restarting the container, jenkins fails to come up, no configs were changed but shows the below error :

```
io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfiguratorException: Invalid configuration elements for type class jenkins.model.GlobalConfigurationCategory$Security : downloadSettings.
Available attributes : apiToken, crumb, globalJobDslSecurityConfiguration, masterKillSwitchConfiguration, queueItemAuthenticator, sSHD, scriptApproval, updateSiteWarningsConfiguration
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.handleUnknown(BaseConfigurator.java:377)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.configure(BaseConfigurator.java:366)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.check(BaseConfigurator.java:287)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.lambda$checkWith$7(ConfigurationAsCode.java:746)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.invokeWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:696)
Caused: io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfiguratorException: security: error configuring 'security' with class io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.GlobalConfigurationCategoryConfigurator configurator
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.invokeWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:702)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.checkWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:746)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:731)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:611)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configure(ConfigurationAsCode.java:292)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.init(ConfigurationAsCode.java:284)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:104)
Caused: java.lang.Error
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:110)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:175)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1121)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:48)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1154)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:965)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:233)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:250)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
security:
  downloadSettings:
    useBrowser: false
```

Jenkins with the configuration as code plugin, will need to remove the `downloadSettings` entry from the configuration file, as per docs in https://jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.204/, in-order to fix above stated error.